# Android Studio - The emulator process for AVD ... was killed

Tags: emulation

I write this message beaucause i have a problem with the emulator in Android Studio.
Last year, i worked with emulator and had no problem.

Since this week, i search to learn flutter with android studio.
So i tried to launch the emulator and ....TADAAAA

"The emulator process for AVD ... was killed". [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvPfT.png)
So i search, follow differente tutorials and i can't found the problem.

I did :

- Unstall and reinstall Android
- Delete and reinstall different emulators [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1x0a.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tOHi.png)
- In SDK Manager :
  delete and reinstall Android 10 and 11 in the SDK Plateforms [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ1ju.png)
  delete and reinstall in SDK Tools Android Emulator, Android SDK Plateform-Tools and HAXM [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YypAg.png)
- Tools, Emulator . The checkbox is empty [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZ87.png)
- The disque is not full [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN5Ga.png)

I follow a lot of tutoriel and videos on youtube like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOK9ZxiBOGg) but the problem stay.

Can you help me please ? I tried to found the solution and i don't know if i can found a stacktrace or logs, like the emulator die directly.

Thank's in advance
Best regard

Comment: Did you try creating a new AVD and running the process on your new AVD? "The emulator process was killed" sounds like a crash in the AVD instead of in your app.

Comment: Yeah, i delete and recreating different AVD many times, but i have everytime the same message

Comment: For information, when i connect my personnal phone (with the developer mode), android studio doesn't detect my phone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

- Delete all emulators
- Then go to Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Uninstall "Android Emulator".
- Under File -> Invalidate Caches / restart ... restart the IDE.
- Reinstall "Android Emulator" and than create a new emulator.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help in my case.

Comment: Did not help to me either. However helps me in another situation.